# Headset (for XBox gaming) with adjustable sidetone

Tags: headset, audio-adapters

tl;dr: (Thanks to [fred_dot_u](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/8930/84)) I'm looking for a gaming headset with adjustable sidetone, for use on an XBox One.

---

One of my kids has gotten into online gaming with friends on XBox One using a Logitech G933 headset.  **The problem:** He can't keep his voice down.  He's like the annoying phone users who become oblivious to how loud they're talking.

My wife says that my first solution – an anti-bark collar – is not acceptable.

So my second idea is to plug the headset through an adjustable microphone feedback device that adds the microphone's audio signal on top of the audio going to the earphones.  As we increase that feedback level he'll not only be aware of how loud he's talking, but then if he gets too loud he'll start a feedback loop.  I figure that will teach him very quickly to keep his voice down.

Does any such device exist, or can some existing device be easily adapted to this purpose?

Answer (score 2):

Part of that which is missing in today's portable communications devices (cellular phones) is a feature of old-time telephones known as sidetone. This is exactly what you describe as feedback. One can hear one's own voice when speaking, with minimal to zero delay. Any appreciable delay becomes comedy material for radio disk jockeys and is riotous.

I did a quick search for "gaming headset with sidetone" and was rewarded with a number of results that would indicate such a product exists. A few clicks in and I discovered that the search results are misleading, as a number of the products did not explicitly state sidetone as a feature.

I also discovered that a few forums have discussions regarding this feature. It is more likely that you would be able to find a product confirmed by a forum user as having that feature, or you may be lucky enough to discover specifications indicating that sidetone or feedback is available.

One post to a forum indicated that windows has the capability to enable the user to select "hear yourself" but I cannot confirm that as I do not have that feature on my system.

The anti-bark collar, while suitable for creating entertaining video, would be providing feedback of limited duration.

Comment: Thank you – just knowing what that feature is called is a tremendous help!  I just updated the title and intro to the OP with this.